# How do I remove non-letters from the beginning of the string

Tags: ruby, regex, substitution, letters

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How do I remove non-letters from the beginning of my string?  I thought I could do something like

```
name ? name.sub(/^[^a-z]*/i, "") : nil
```

but this neglects things like an accented a ("á") or that type of "u" with the dots above it.

I don't consider numbers or punctuation marks letters so I would want them removed from the beginning of my string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match non-letters with a Unicode category class `\P{L}`:

```
name = name.sub(/\A\P{L}+/, "")
```

**Pattern details**:

- `\A` - start of string anchor
- `\P{L}+` - one or more (`+`) characters other than letters (`\P{L}`).

Comment: The same regex but with a bit different notation: `/\A\p{^L}+/`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `^` means beginning of line in Ruby, while `\A` means beginning of string. The `^` version will appear to work on single line strings, but can be easily confused with newline characters.